# Деплой телеграм бота (Flask, Python, Gunicorn)

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Залил бота на вебхук, на локали всё прекрасно работает, запускаю на сервере через фласк всё топ, запускаю через команду gunicorn main:app - ничего не работает, почему так?
Решил попробовать запустить с обычным приложением
`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

`
И оно заработало, как я понял, проблема в ssl верификации, вопрос, как её подрубить к уникорну?

файл services
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл который находиться в etc nginx sites available
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что выдается по status
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот журнал проекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот журнал ошибок nginx
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru ? `(venv) $ gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app`

Comment: Оно не работает, я б скрин приложил но не могу 
`[2020-09-30 13:35:17 +0300] [4746] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-09-30 13:35:17 +0300] [4746] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (4746)
[2020-09-30 13:35:17 +0300] [4746] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-09-30 13:35:17 +0300] [4749] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4749
`
И на сайт перехожу он еле-еле грузит его , даже по стандартному шаблону с сайта (пустое фласк приложение), + мне нужно ещё ssl сертификацию подрубить

Comment: отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавьте код/конфиг

Comment: Конфига нет, я не знаю как его составлять и где его хранить.

Comment: тогда читайте статью по ссылке из моего комментария, там всё подробно и доступно написано, сам по ней настраивал не один раз

Comment: Ничего не вышло, в вопросе все данные

Answer (score 2):

Рабочий пример

```
server {
    listen 5555;
    server_name 15.17.8.26;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/bot.sock;
    }
}


[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/opt/bot
Environment=/opt/bot/bin
ExecStart=/opt/bot/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/run/bot.sock wsgi:app
```

Comment: Вообще не работает, ругаеться на ошибку с proxy pass и на предпоследнюю , на сайте они отличны и с сайта они работают, ну как, ошибок сама система не выдает, но на деле оно не работает